# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':base:builder:sourcesJar'

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-source

When I was building the [Android Gradle Plugin source code](http://tools.android.com/build/gradleplugin), I always get the following error! I use **./gradlew assemble** command.
I try to check the 'tools/dx' dir and found that it is not a gradle module.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/zhangyang/aosp/gradle_3.1.2/tools/base/build-system/builder/build.gradle' line: 133

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':base:builder:jar'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':base:builder:provided'.
 > Could not resolve project :dx.
     Required by:
        project :base:builder
        > Project :base:builder declares a dependency from configuration 'provided' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :dx.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
```